# not able to connect to test.mosquitto.org

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, nodemcu

I am working on esp8266 and trying to connect to test.mosquitto.org.
here is what I got from net

```
m = mqtt.Client("clientid", 60, "user", "password")
m:on("connect", function(con) print ("connected") end)
m:on("offline", function(con) print ("offline") end)
m:on("message", function(conn, topic, data) 
  print(topic .. ":" ) 
  if data ~= nil then
    print(data)
  end
end)

m:connect("http://test.mosquitto.org/", 1883, 0, function(conn) print("connected") end)
m:subscribe("/topic",0, function(conn) print("subscribe success") end)
m:publish("/topic","hello",0,0, function(conn) print("sent") end)
m:close();
```

I am not sure from where to get clientId ,user and pass,

here what I am getting :
DNS retry 1!
DNS retry 2!
DNS retry 3!
DNS retry 4!
DNS Fail!

Comment: The answer was given by @hardillb. Also have a look at the example at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware#connect-to-mqtt-broker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the *http://* at the start of the connect string and the */* at the end

The connect command wants just a hostname not a URL and even if it did you would want to pass *tcp://test.mosquitto.org* or *mqtt://test.mosquitto.org*

```
...
m:connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 0, function(conn) print("connected") end)
...
```

Also as an aside, your topics should not start with a /, this just adds an extra unnecessary null to the start of the topic tree.

Comment: How would you go about connecting to an address like tcp://test.mosquitto.org?

Comment: @AnchithAcharya By doing what it says in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Try with the IP instead of the name:

```
m:connect("85.119.83.194", 1883, 0, function(conn) print("connected") end)
```

if that works that means that you are having a problem resolving the name of the website (for whatever reason).

Comment: This works for me. I am running my client on RPi. Could you please guide me how can resolve the issue for resolving the name?

Answer (score 0):

RE the original question: I use it without the last arguments as

```
m = mqtt.Client(clientID, 60)
```

and `clientID` is any name you want, to distinguish yourself from other clients (e.g. `"Ankit"`).

The topic should be more descriptive of the payload (e.g. `"message"`) and not a generic `/topic`.

Also note the earlier answers, for the connection use an IP (e.g. `"85.119.83.194"`) or a hostname (e.g. `"test.mosquitto.org"`) of the server.

HTH